# In tsc --build how to overcome --incremental and --tsBuildInfoFile

Tags: typescript, tsc

Different parts of my typescript application lives in different subdirectories. In the top directory a `tsconfig.json` references the various sub-tsconfigs. I build the application by `tsc --build` This works perfectly. All subproject have `incremental: true` defined and some also `tsBuildInfoFile`.

Now I want to force a rebuild. Simple for each subproject by `tsc -p subproj --incremental false --tsBuildInfoFile null` but how to pass these options to `--build`?

When I tried I receive:

```
client/tsconfig.json:16:9 - error TS5069: Option 'tsBuildInfoFile' cannot be specified without specifying option 'incremental' or option 'composite'.

16         "incremental": true,
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

client/tsconfig.json:17:9 - error TS5069: Option 'tsBuildInfoFile' cannot be specified without specifying option 'incremental' or option 'composite'.

17         "tsBuildInfoFile": "./tsconfig.tsbuildinfo",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing `incremental` breaks related options. To force a rebuild use the option `--force`

Comment: I got error TS5093: Compiler option '--force' may only be used with '--build' ;-(

Comment: But just `--incremental false` works for me, I just wanted the first build in `--watch` to be a complete fresh build.